# Which of these statements is correct?

Tags: difference

I sometimes get confused about the which of these statements.

1. I saw you entering Daniel's room in the morning.
2. I saw you enter Daniel's room in the morning.

Do the above sentences have the same meanings or are different?

Answer (score 2):

The two sentences differ slightly in the statement of exactly *what* was seen.

In sentence #1, the direct object is "you". The information about entering Daniel's room is contained in a [phrasal] modifier to "you". This makes the essence of the statement, "I saw you". The fact that you were entering Daniel's room at the time may be just a detail to identify the time of the sighting, or some other non-critical information that the speaker happened to mention. The main point of the sentence is just "I saw you." For example, perhaps the speaker just meant to say he knew you were awake already because he saw you walking around and entering the room.

In sentence #2, the thing that was seen is identified by the entire clause, "you enter Daniel's room in the morning". The fact that you entered Daniel's room is now part of the object of the sentence (not a mere modifier).

This difference might seem unimportant, but it is significant to how we interpret the two sentences.

Why is the speaker in #2 making a deliberate point to tell you that he saw *your entry into the room*? It sounds like entering Daniel's room is somehow remarkable. ... Maybe that is something you should not be doing?

On the other hand, the speaker's choice of the word "entering" instead of just plain "going into" makes both statements sound a little bit formal and legalistic, as if "*entering*" Daniel's room is not a simple, casual thing, but an activity that must be stated carefully and precisely.

The word "enter" gives both sentences 1 and 2 the flavor of an accusation, but in sentence 2 that implication is even more noticeable because of the way the activity of "entering Daniel's room" has moved into the main structure of the sentence.